# on change event is not working on custom select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to follow below example for custom select but I am not able to perform on change event and on focus event.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

I am not able to perform any event for option value . So how can I perform any event on select?

here is my javascript code

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
     except the current select box:*/
  var x,
    y,
    i,
    xl,
    yl,
    arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i);
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
            then close all select boxes:*/

let selectDiv = document.getElementById('selectopt');

selectDiv.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('Mouse Clicked');
});

let changeEvent = new Event('change');
selectDiv.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```html
<div class="custom-select inputfieldwithoutanimation" style="width: 737px">
  <select id="selectopt" class="inputfield-control-withoutanimation">
    <option value="0">Choose:</option>
    <option value="1">Department - A</option>
    <option value="2">Department - B</option>
    <option value="3">Department - C</option>
  </select>
  <label class="form-label-withoutanimation selectcls">Department</label>
</div>
 css code

         <style>
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  .custom-select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 24px;
  }

  .custom-select select {
    display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
  }

  .select-selected {
    background-color: white;
  }

  /*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
  .select-selected:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 21px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 6px solid black;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  }

  /*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
  .select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
    top: 16px;
  }

  .select-selected {
    border: 1.5px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 737px;
  }

  /*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
  .select-items div,
  .select-selected {
    color: #000;
    padding: 13px 16px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    /* border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent; */
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
  }

  /*style items (options):*/
  .select-items {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ecf7fe;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
  }

  /*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
  .select-hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .select-items div:hover,
  .same-as-selected {
    background-color: #ccecfe;
  }

  .dropdown-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Only form control elements fire `change` event, you've to emulate the event with click event.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Perhaps add some CSS? What is expected behaviour? Also w3schools is not an excellent resource. Many example of poor coding that so many beginners pick up and never lose.

Comment: Also `l` is a REALLY bad variable name when you loop since it looks like `1` in the editor - instead use `len` if you want to keep it short

Comment: @Teemu Could it be that I'm missing something here? Select is a form element and it fires the change event just fine? https://jsfiddle.net/nzf4chsL/

Comment: @icecub sorry I forget to add css , I have added you can check now

Comment: @icecub Yup, but OP wants to attach a change event to their custom select element, which is built-up of div elements. Or did I miss something fundamental parts here, I based my comment on this line: `selectDiv.addEventListener('change', ...)`, assuming `selectDiv` really is a `div` element.